# Which Json structure suitable for this work?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

This function generate dummy data for this Structure .

```
private void createDummyData() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

        VerticalDataModel dm = new VerticalDataModel();

        dm.setSectionTitle("Section " + i);

        ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
            singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
        }

        dm.setSingleItemModelha(singleItem);

        allSampleData.add(dm);

    }
```

[image]

Know for generating this data from internet , i need json structor for this work .(I use volley library)
Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 data : [
         {
          "title":"section1",
          "items":[{"name":"item1","url":"url1"},{"name":"item2","url":"url2"}]
         },
         {
          "title":"section2",
          "items":[{"name":"item3","url":"url3"},{"name":"item4","url":"url4"}]
         }
        ]
}
```

so basically you have array of objects which contains title and items as its property. Again items is another array of objects which contains name and url as its property.